# How to Sort a Dataframe in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I have a dataframe:

```
# +---+--------+---------+
# | id|  rank  |  value  |
# +---+--------+---------+
# |  1|    A   |    10   |
# |  2|    B   |    46   |
# |  3|    D   |     8   |
# |  4|    C   |     8   |
# +---+--------+---------+
```

I want to sort it by value, then rank. This seems like it should be simple, but I'm not seeing how it's done in the documentation or SO for Pyspark, only for R and Scala.

This is how it should look after sorting, .show() should print:

```
# +---+--------+---------+
# | id|  rank  |  value  |
# +---+--------+---------+
# |  4|    C   |     8   |
# |  3|    D   |     8   |
# |  1|    A   |    10   |
# |  2|    B   |    46   |
# +---+--------+---------+
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

say your dataframe is stored in a variable called df
you'd do `df.orderBy('value').show()` to get it sorted

Comment: That worked as well as adding multiple values as gasparms suggested.

Answer (score 12):

```
df.orderBy(["value", "rank"], ascending=[1, 1])
```

Reference: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.orderBy

Comment: you can also use ascending=[True, True] (maybe more readable)